# Application and DLL using Direct3D independently

Tags: dll, direct3d

If an application which is using Direct3D to draw graphics loads a DLL that wants to do the same (although independently, in a different window), is that safe?

Also, can two IDirect3DDevice9's render to the same window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, a DLL can use DirectX independently of it's loading application. I still don't know if two apps can draw to the same window.